# jdbc template SQL syntax error

Tags: sql, spring-mvc, jdbc

```
public List<Product> getListOfProductsWhere(String name, int productscol, double cost, String check) {
    List<Product> listOfProducts = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE %?%,
            returnArray(name, productscol, cost, check), new RowMapper<Product>() {
                @Override
                public Product mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    Product product = new Product();
                    product.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                    product.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                    product.setDate(rs.getDate("date"));
                    product.setProductscol(rs.getInt("productscol"));
                    product.setCost(rs.getDouble("cost"));
                    product.setId_user(rs.getInt("users_user_id"));
                    return product;
                }
            });
    return listOfProducts;
}
```

Ошибка

> Mon Apr 25 23:40:21 SAMT 2016 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). PreparedStatementCallback;
>   bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE %?%]; nested
>   exception is
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'chocolate'%'
>   at line 1

Comment: Может, добавите своё описание кода и проблемы, а не только копипаст?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE %?%

Эта ошибка означает, что знаки процента должны принадлежать не самому запросу, как в вашем примере, а аргументу запроса. Соответственно, понадобится дополнительно обрабатывать приходящий аргумент и добавлять к нему знаки процента с двух сторон.

К слову, не забудьте также экранировать эти самые знаки процента в самом аргументе.